# Error install bower/npm windows 10

Tags: windows, bower

I am running:
Bower install ng-file-upload --save
And give me the following error:

```
Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\jlgar\AppData\Local\Temp\DESKTOP-OEBUEM1-jlgar\bower\43ae8222903956c0d7a08b25b4a57aa3-8392-4be1lK\archive.tar.gz.1071277013' -> 'C:\Users\jlgar\AppData\Local\Temp\DESKTOP-OEBUEM1-jlgar\bower\43ae8222903956c0d7a08b25b4a57aa3-8392-4be1lK\archive.tar.gz'
at Error (native)
```

I have tried to:
  Reinstall bower
  Delete those routes in the cache
  I enter the console as administrator

No option works for me, what I do find strange is that you want to move the same file on the same path. It's strange. Do not?
Someone can help me, because I can not install anything, with NPM the same thing happens to me.

Thank you

Comment: did you try clearing cache???

Comment: I have manually deleted the folder and have executed : bower clean cache , But the error remains

Comment: It was the antivirus. What a despair of windows. Jejeje